# What is the Standard for Handling Endianness With Interop?

Tags: c#, assembly, cryptography

I created a very simple DLL for Speck in (granted, probably inefficient) ASM.  I connected to it in C# using InteropServices.

When I tested this crypto with the test vectors provided in the [paper describing the algorithm](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/404.pdf), I found that the only way to get them to come out right was to "flip" the key and the plain text, and then to "flip" the crypto at the end for a match.  So an endianness issue I guess.  I have seen the same, for example, between a reference implementation of Serpent and TrueCrypt's version -- they produce the same result only with the bytes in the reverse order.

I will post my assembly code and my C# code for reference, though it may not be critical to see the code in order to understand my question.  In the C# code is a click event handler that checks the DLL for consistency with the test vectors.  As you can also see there, the program has to do a lot of array flipping in that handler to get the match.

So the question I have been working towards is this.  Should I "flip" those arrays inside the DLL to account for endianness?  Or should I leave it to the caller (also me, but C# side)?  Or am I making mountains out of molehills and I should just ignore endianness at this point?  I am not planning to sell the silly thing, so there is no worry about compatibility issues, but I am a stickler for doing things right, so I am hoping you all can guide me on the best practice here if there is one.

ASM:

```
.code ; the beginning of the code
 ; section
WinMainCRTStartup proc h:DWORD, r:DWORD, u:DWORD ; the dll entry point
 mov rax, 1 ; if eax is 0, the dll won't
 ; start
 ret ; return
WinMainCRTStartup Endp ; end of the dll entry

_DllMainCRTStartup proc h:DWORD, r:DWORD, u:DWORD ; the dll entry point
 mov rax, 1 ; if eax is 0, the dll won't
 ; start
 ret ; return
_DllMainCRTStartup Endp                                 

SpeckEncrypt proc plaintText:QWORD, cipherText:QWORD, Key:QWORD
; Pass in 3 addresses pointing to the base of the plainText, cipherText, and         Key arrays
; These come in as RCX, RDX, and R8, respectively
; I will use These, RAX, and R9 through R15 for my working space.  Will do 128 bit block, 128 bit key sizes, but they will fit nicely in 64 bit registers

; simple prologue, pushing ebp and ebx and the R# registers, and moving the value of esp into ebp for the duration of the proc  
push rbp
mov rbp,rsp
push rbx
push R9
push R10
push R11
push R12
push R13
push R14
push R15

; Move data into the registers for processing
mov r9,[rcx] ; rcx holds the memory location of the first 64 bits of plainText.  Move this into R9.  This is plainText[0] 
mov r10,[rcx+8] ; put next 64 bits into R10.  This is plainText[1]
;NOTE that the address of the cipherText is in RDX but we will fill r11 and r12 with values pointed at by RCX.  This is per the algorithm.  We will use RDX to output the final bytes
mov r11,[rcx] ; cipherText[0] = plainText[0]
mov r12,[rcx+8] ; cipherText[1] = plainText[1] 
mov r13, [r8] ;First 64 bits of key.  This is Key[0]
mov r14, [r8+8] ; Next 64 bits of key.  This is Key[1]

push rcx ; I could get away without this and loop in another register, but I want to count my loop in rcx so I free it up for that
mov rcx, 0 ; going to count up from here to 32.  Would count down but the algorithm uses the counter value in one permutation, so going to count up

EncryptRoundFunction:
ror r12,8
add r12,r11
xor r12,r13
rol r11,3
xor r11,r12

ror r14,8
add r14,r13
xor r14,rcx
rol r13,3
xor r13,r14

inc rcx
cmp rcx, 32
jne EncryptRoundFunction

pop rcx
; Move cipherText into memory pointed at by RDX.  We won't bother copying the Key or plainText back out
mov [rdx],r11
mov [rdx+8],r12

; Now the epilogue, returning values from the stack into non-volatile registers.
pop R15
pop R14
pop R13
pop R12
pop R11
pop R10
pop R9    
pop rbx    
pop rbp
ret ; return eax
SpeckEncrypt endp ; end of the function

SpeckDecrypt proc cipherText:QWORD, plainText:QWORD, Key:QWORD
; Pass in 3 addresses pointing to the base of the cipherText, plainText, and Key arrays
; These come in as RCX, RDX, and R8, respectively
; I will use These, RAX, and R9 through R15 for my working space.  Will do 128 bit block, 128 bit key sizes, but they will fit nicely in 64 bit registers

; simple prologue, pushing ebp and ebx and the R# registers, and moving the value of esp into ebp for the duration of the proc  
push rbp
mov rbp,rsp
push rbx
push R9
push R10
push R11
push R12
push R13
push R14
push R15

; Move data into the registers for processing
mov r9,[rcx] ; rcx holds the memory location of the first 64 bits of cipherText.  Move this into R9.  This is cipherText[0] 
mov r10,[rcx+8] ; put next 64 bits into R10.  This is cipherText[1]
;NOTE that the address of the plainText is in RDX but we will fill r11 and r12 with values pointed at by RCX.  This is per the algorithm.  We will use RDX to output the final bytes
mov r11,[rcx] ; plainText[0] = cipherText[0]
mov r12,[rcx+8] ; plainText[1] = cipherText[1] 
mov r13, [r8] ;First 64 bits of key.  This is Key[0]
mov r14, [r8+8] ; Next 64 bits of key.  This is Key[1]

push rcx ; I could get away without this and loop in another register, but I want to count my loop in rcx so I free it up for that
mov rcx, 0 ; We will count up while making the round keys

DecryptMakeRoundKeys:
; On encrypt we could make each key just as we needed it.  But here we need the keys in reverse order.  To undo round 31 of encryption, for example, we need round key 31.

; So we will make them all and push them on the stack, pop them off again as we need them in the main DecryptRoundFunction
; I should pull this off and call it for encrypt and decrypt to save space, but for now will have it separate

; push r13 at the beginning of the process because we need a "raw" key by the time we reach decrypt round 0
; We will not push r14 because that half of the key is only used here in the round key generation function.
; We don't need it in the decrypt rounds
push r13

ror r14,8
add r14,r13
xor r14,rcx
rol r13,3
xor r13,r14

inc rcx
cmp rcx, 32
jne DecryptMakeRoundKeys

mov rcx, 32
DecryptRoundFunction:
dec rcx
pop r13

xor r11,r12
ror r11,3
xor r12,r13
sub r12,r11
rol r12,8

cmp rcx, 0
jne DecryptRoundFunction


pop rcx
; Move cipherText into memory pointed at by RDX.  We won't bother copying the Key or plainText back out
mov [rdx],r11
mov [rdx+8],r12

; Now the epilogue, returning values from the stack into non-volatile registers.
pop R15
pop R14
pop R13
pop R12
pop R11
pop R10
pop R9    
pop rbx    
pop rbp
ret ; return eax
SpeckDecrypt endp ; end of the function

End ; end of the dll
```

And the C#:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SpeckDLLTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        byte[] key = { 0x0f, 0x0e, 0x0d, 0x0c, 0x0b, 0x0a, 0x09, 0x08, 0x07, 0x06, 0x05, 0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00 };
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Array.Reverse(key);
        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Length.ToString();
            if (richTextBox1.Text != "")
            {
                byte[] plainText = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(richTextBox1.Text);
                byte[] cipherText = new byte[plainText.Length];

                Thread t = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    cipherText = Encrypt(plainText);
                    BeginInvoke(new Action(() => richTextBox2.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText)));
                });
                t.Start();
                t.Join();
                t.Abort();


                byte[] plainAgain = new byte[cipherText.Length];
                t = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        plainAgain = Decrypt(cipherText);
                        BeginInvoke(new Action(() => richTextBox3.Text = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(plainAgain)));
                    });
                t.Start();
                t.Join();
                t.Abort();
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox2.Text = "";
                richTextBox3.Text = "";
            }
        }

        private byte[] Decrypt(byte[] cipherText)
        {
            int blockCount = cipherText.Length / 16;
            if (cipherText.Length % 16 != 0) blockCount++;
            Array.Resize(ref cipherText, blockCount * 16);
            byte[] plainText = new byte[cipherText.Length];
            unsafe
            {
                fixed (byte* plaintextPointer = plainText, ciphertextPointer = cipherText, keyPointer = key)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < blockCount; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
                        {
                            UnsafeMethods.SpeckDecrypt(ciphertextPointer + i * 16, plaintextPointer + i * 16, keyPointer);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return plainText;
        }

        private byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plainText)
        {
            int blockCount = plainText.Length / 16;
            if (plainText.Length % 16 != 0) blockCount++;
            Array.Resize(ref plainText, blockCount * 16);
            byte[] cipherText = new byte[plainText.Length];
            unsafe
            {
                fixed (byte* plaintextPointer = plainText, ciphertextPointer = cipherText, keyPointer = key)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < blockCount; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
                        {
                            UnsafeMethods.SpeckEncrypt(plaintextPointer + i * 16, ciphertextPointer + i * 16, keyPointer);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return cipherText;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] plainText = { 0x6c, 0x61, 0x76, 0x69, 0x75, 0x71, 0x65, 0x20, 0x74, 0x69, 0x20, 0x65, 0x64, 0x61, 0x6d, 0x20 };
            byte[] key = { 0x0f, 0x0e, 0x0d, 0x0c, 0x0b, 0x0a, 0x09, 0x08, 0x07, 0x06, 0x05, 0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00 };
            byte[] testVector = { 0xa6, 0x5d, 0x98, 0x51, 0x79, 0x78, 0x32, 0x65, 0x78, 0x60, 0xfe, 0xdf, 0x5c, 0x57, 0x0d, 0x18 };

            Array.Reverse(key);
            Array.Reverse(plainText);

            byte[] cipherText = new byte[16];
            unsafe
            {
                fixed (byte* plaintextPointer = plainText, ciphertextPointer = cipherText, keyPointer = key)
                {
                    UnsafeMethods.SpeckEncrypt(plaintextPointer, ciphertextPointer, keyPointer);
                    Array.Reverse(cipherText);
                    bool testBool = true;
                    for (int i = 0; i < cipherText.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (testVector[i] != cipherText[i]) testBool = false;
                    }
                    if (testBool == false) MessageBox.Show("Failed!");
                    else MessageBox.Show("Passed!");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class UnsafeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("Speck.dll")]
        unsafe public extern static void SpeckEncrypt(byte* plainText, byte* cipherText, byte* Key);
        [DllImport("Speck.dll")]
        unsafe public extern static void SpeckDecrypt(byte* cipherText, byte* plainText, byte* Key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use ABI specific [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) and [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_of_hardware)

Comment: Those calling conventions talk more about who cleans up the stack, etc.  I had read them, which is what gave me the idea to ask here if there are conventions on, for example, endianness (if the convention is for caller or callee to adjust for endianness).  I could not find that stated anywhere.  I am inferring from your post that the caller (C# in this case) should do it.  I hope I am inferring correctly.  Thank you for the comment.

Comment: [_" Intel 64 and IA-32 processors are “little endian” machines"_](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.pdf) which means that all low level code (both callers and callees) use same endian-ness. See also [MSDN: x64 Software Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kcdt6fy.aspx) for register usage and order of parameters

Comment: Yep, read most all of that already.  My problem is that my case is so special I suppose.  I know that the processor is little endian, but the problem is that adhering to the specifications, which I believed to be for little endian processors, everything is mirrored.  So I figured flipping arrays is inevitable at this point and just wondered if it is more practical to do the flip inside the DLL or to have the caller do it.  Inside the DLL would be faster performance but less flexible.  I haven't seen any documents anywhere saying if endianness should be adjusted for by caller or callee.

Comment: The recommended way is to use agreed and optimized convention with reduced overhead by all parties (`ABI`). The array flipping should be removed altogether and all parties should use same endianness. That is the recommended way. Although there is a [System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention(v=vs.100).aspx), there is no endianness configuration option , as far as I know

Comment: If you're flipping entire arrays then it's not an endian issue. Byte arrays don't have an endianness. If you had to reverse every 64-bit value then that would be an endian problem.

Comment: Just to clarify, Speck 128/128 uses 64-bit words, so when I pass them in, they are handled internally that way.  But the plain text I encrypt comes from GetBytes.  So although I could convert it to an array of longs before passing it in, the DLL doesn't seem to care.  But although I do follow that bytes arrays don't have endianness, I don't follow how this is not an endianness issue.  Simplifying, if the test vector says use a key of 00 01 and plaintext of 00 02 to get ciphertext of 00 03, I actually have to pass in 01 00 and 02 00 and get 03 00 back.  Except in 16 byte chunks of course.

Comment: I actually modeled Speck in Python and C# directly before trying it with Assembly, and I had this same issue every time even though my implementation looks exactly as specified.

Comment: It seems that the only problem is your reading of the byte array literals. `a[]={0x0A, 0x0B}` means `a[0]==0x0A` and `a[1]==0x0B` and so on

Comment: Simon128/128   Key: 0f0e0d0c0b0a0908 0706050403020100    Plaintext: 6373656420737265 6c6c657661727420  Ciphertext: 49681b1e1e54fe3f 65aa832af84e0bbc   All of this is from the specification.  But in fact I have to make the array key be {0x00,0x01,0x02,etc.}  And alalogous "flipping" of the plain text yields "flipped" output.  I do know how array elements are numbered.

Comment: By the way in case you wonder, if you put the key in per specification and the plain text in per specification, the output is nothing close to the predicted output.  There is no symmetry there (and indeed there shouldn't be).  The only way to get it to work was to flip key and plain text, then accept flipped cipher text.

Comment: Sorry a couple comments up I posted the test vector for Simon 128/128 in error.  Here is for Speck 128/128.  Speck128/128
Key: 0f0e0d0c0b0a0908 0706050403020100
Plaintext: 6c61766975716520 7469206564616d20
Ciphertext: a65d985179783265 7860fedf5c570d18  But again I am forced to feed the algorithm the key with 0x00 in the [0] element, the plain text with the 0x20 in the [0] element, and get back the cipher text with 0x18 in the [0] element.  It's a small thing but . . . I dunno, was just hoping to learn how I might best deal with it, even if that means I should ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether someone might like it or not, the de facto standard for byte order when it comes to networking and cryptography is **big-endian** (most significant byte first — the “natural” order). This applies not only to serialization of data for inter-system exchange, but to intra-system API as well and for any other case where caller is not supposed to be aware of callee internals. This convention does not have anything to do with endianness of particular hardware and popularity of such hardware. It just sets the default format for exchanged data, so that both lower-level and higher-level programs may pass data around without regard to their degree of awareness of what this data contains and how it is processed.

However, if the caller is supposed to be tightly coupled with the callee, it may be more convenient and performance-wise to pass the data in a more preprocessed form, especially if some of that data remains constant across invocations. For example, if we are dealing with asymmetric cryptography, it may be easier and faster to call the core functions with all data already translated to big integers, and for those we may prefer *little-endian digit order* (a “digit” or a “limb” is usually a half of largest available register) even on a *big-endian byte order* hardware — simply because such an order of digits is more useful for arbitrary-precision math library. But those details should not be visible to the outside world — for anyone else, we are accepting and returning big-endian bytestream.

---

Regarding your specific task.

1. As @RossRidge already pointed out, you are probably very wrong if your are simply flipping entire arrays, — you should swap bytes (`BSWAP`) in particular pieces being processed rather than inverting the order of those pieces besides that.
2. Chances are high that you are very overestimating your ability to write efficient machine code: for example, you don't interleave instructions with unrelated registers for better out-of-order execution, your loop is not aligned, you use counter increase to N instead of decrease to zero. Of course, that code will still be 10x faster than .Net anyway, but I strongly recommend you to write an implementation in C and benchmark — to get amazed of how good a compiler (MSVC, GCC) may be at optimizing even a straight-though written program (believe me, I once committed the same mistake when trying to accomplish the same task). If performance is not a big issue, do not mess with unmanaged code at all, — because it is just an external non-portable dependency that increases required trust level for you .Net application.
3. Use .Net functions dealing with bytes with caution, because they are very inconsistent with regard to endianness: `BitConverter` uses host byte order, `StreamReader` always sticks to little-endian, and `String` is all about the encoding given (of all UTF encodings, only UTF-8 is endian-agnostic).

That are the issues I noticed at first glance. There may be more of them.

Comment: Thank you for the very good response here.  So from the main part of your post, I gather I should do any flipping inside the unmanaged code if at all, to keep things tidy for the caller.  As to your numbered points 1 and 2:

Comment: 1)  I didn't go into all the detail on this I might have, so I understand RossRidge's assumption and yours, that maybe I am flipping large arrays (maybe a whole message in a byte array).  But to be clear, the only reason I was flipping the whole array was because the array was exactly 16 bytes (one block for the encryption algorithm) long.  If I had had 10 blocks or 160 bytes in the array, I would not have flipped the whole array but would have flipped byte order on elements 0 - 15, then on elements 16 - 31, and so on.

Comment: 2)  I assure you I do not overestimate my ability to write assembly.  A couple weeks ago I had never done it, except a tiny program on HesMon when I was a kid.  I am just learning here, though I admit the project is a tough one for a beginner.  As for the loop counting up, I explained in the in-program comment why I did that.  If the loop counted down, I would have had extra math to do each round because the value of the counter is used in the algorithm.  But since asking this question I did switch to Fortran for now, passing by reference rather than by pointer for the same reason you gave.

Comment: That's exactly the catch with machine code optimization: 2 counters (one counting up as an array index / iteration number, one counting down for easier loop condition checking with `DEC; JNZ` instead of `INC; CMP; JNE`) may still perform faster than 1 counter, — despite having to modify both of them, because this modification may be done in parallel and thus out of order. However, this is not guaranteed, — as always, you have to properly benchmark all versions.

Comment: Another optimization technique to consider with that kind of algorithms is *loop unrolling*: instead of writing a regular loop with a counter (or two counters) you may explicitly code each iteration with fixed counter value and no condition checking. However, this gives no guarantee on performance increase either, as larger code requires additional analysis by CPU and consumes extra instruction cache. The more so that writing even 32 iterations by hand is not easy, especially while you are still experimenting with loop body, — so you may want to write a code generator.

Comment: I actually did use Python to write some code like that for a different project.  It would be very easy for me to do the same with Python on this one, or to write a macro in the assembler itself to unroll the loop.  But at this point it's all on hold.  Fortran is faster development and blindingly fast execution.  I have not raced the Fortran against the above assembly, but I am sure they are close.  Only annoyance is that where the above made a 2KB DLL, Fortran made a 78KB exe.  Have not made a DLL in Fortran for it yet but I expect similar bloat.  Still, memory is cheap...